# Error: object 'result' not found when clustering data

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Here is the code:

```
n <- length(unique(data$vehicleType))
set.seed(42)
result <- kmeans(data.norm, n)
result
```

Error message:

```
Error: object 'result' not found
```

Comment: Did you execute ```result <- kmeans(data.norm, n)```? Because this error means that ```R``` can not find the variable ```result```.

Comment: it gives the error message: Error: number of cluster centres must lie between 1 and nrow(x)

Comment: Well, this is your real problem then.

Comment: What is the value of ```n``` and what is the output of ```length(data.norm)```?

Comment: Did you mean ```data$norm``` instead of ```data.norm```? If not, how did you create ```data.norm```?

Comment: The code is supposed to show this: K-means clustering with 6 clusters of sizes 14, 39, 27, 96, 2, 36

Cluster means:
          RI         Na         Mg          Al         Si
1  2.0913049 -1.4301315 -1.6670269 -0.09709777 -0.4115854
2  0.9929998  0.6541740  0.2544397 -0.79918559 -0.9877236
3 -0.6238936  1.4793904 -1.6629186  1.54874548  0.5458284
4 -0.4163779 -0.3027485  0.4577478 -0.07408797  0.3083834
5 -1.7058456 -0.4872015 -1.8611468  3.17482441 -2.6608299
6 -0.2160045 -0.4276731  0.5025706 -0.23682568  0.1461916

Comment: If you know that you are supposed to have 6 clusters you can directly use that. I posted an answer, please have a look. However, I think that you problem pertains to the variable ```data.norm```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the job, based on the answers in the comments.

```r
set.seed(42)
result <- kmeans(data.norm, 6)
result
```